# Error "Please enter sold to party or ship to party" while calling BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1

Tags: c#, .net, sap-erp, sap-dotnet-connector

I am trying to integrate SAP ERP with .NET web application using SAP .NET Connector.

I have successfully connected to the SAP system but when I try to create a sales order in SAP using `BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1` I get following error:

> Please enter sold to party or ship to party.

The code snippet I use:

```
    public class CreateSalesOrder
    {
    public string  CreateOrder(RfcDestination destination)
    {
        try
        {
            RfcRepository repo = destination.Repository;
            IRfcFunction salesDoc = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1");
            IRfcFunction salesDocCommit = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT");

            IRfcStructure salesHeader = salesDoc.GetStructure("ORDER_HEADER_IN");

            IRfcTable salesItems = salesDoc.GetTable("ORDER_ITEMS_IN");
            IRfcTable salesPartners = salesDoc.GetTable("ORDER_PARTNERS");
            
            IRfcStructure salesItemsStruct = salesItems.Metadata.LineType.CreateStructure();
            IRfcStructure salesPartnersStruct = salesPartners.Metadata.LineType.CreateStructure();
            IRfcStructure salesPartnersStructRow2 = salesPartners.Metadata.LineType.CreateStructure();

            //Sales Header
            salesHeader.SetValue("DOC_TYPE", "ZDLR");
            salesHeader.SetValue("SALES_ORG", "1000");
            salesHeader.SetValue("DISTR_CHAN", "00");
            salesHeader.SetValue("DIVISION", "00");
            salesHeader.SetValue("SALES_OFF", "1001");

            //Sales Items
            salesItemsStruct.SetValue("ITM_NUMBER", "323");
            salesItemsStruct.SetValue("PLANT", "1001");
            salesItemsStruct.SetValue("MATERIAL", "20000206");
            salesItemsStruct.SetValue("TARGET_QTY", "200");
            salesItemsStruct.SetValue("REQ_QTY", "200");
            
            // Partner
            salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_ROLE", "SP");
            salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_NUMB", "102003");
          

            RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(destination);
            salesDoc.Invoke(destination);
            salesDocCommit.Invoke(destination);
            RfcSessionManager.EndContext(destination);
            return "";
        }

        catch (RfcCommunicationException e)
        {
            return e.ToString();
            
        }
        catch (RfcLogonException e)
        {
            // user could not logon...
            return e.ToString();
        }
        catch (RfcAbapRuntimeException e)
        {
            // serious problem on ABAP system side...
            return e.ToString();
        }
        catch (RfcAbapBaseException e)
        {
            return e.ToString();
            // The function module returned an ABAP exception, an ABAP message
            // or an ABAP class-based exception...
        }

    }
}
```

Please, suggest what I am doing wrong in the call. I properly pass partner details in the following code snippet:

```
     // Partner
            salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_ROLE", "SP");
            salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_NUMB", "102003");
```

Thanks,
Naveed

Comment: According to error message, you mismatched the BAPI signature. Can you provide signature of BAPI you're calling?

Comment: I am using the BAPI "BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1", i am providing the PARTN_ROLE and PARTN_NUMB fields but still i am getting this error, is there any thing i am missing in code or I am providing the partner information in a wrong manner, please suggest appreciate your help. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

sold_to_party and ship_to_party are mandantory fields.

See:
[BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1](http://www.se80.co.uk/sapfms/b/bapi/bapi_salesorder_createfromdat1.htm)

And:
As far as I remember, you have to add the created structures and tables to the function

```
RfcRepository repo = destination.Repository;
IRfcFunction salesDoc = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1");
IRfcStructure salesHeader = salesDoc.GetStructure("ORDER_HEADER_IN");
salesHeader.SetValue("DOC_TYPE", "ZDLR");

salesDoc.SetStructure(salesHeader);

salesDoc.Invoke(destination);
```

Comment: Fields are already provided - as user2320868 mentioned in comment above: 
"..i am providing the PARTN_ROLE and PARTN_NUMB fields but still i am getting this error, is there any thing i am missing in code or I am providing the partner information in a wrong manner..."

Comment: But he is not providing the field sold_to_party and ship_to_party. I can not find them in the code snippet above.

Comment: I am providing the partner information using the code:                salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_ROLE", "SP");
            salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_NUMB", "102003"); can you guide me how to provide the fields Sold_to_party and Ship_to_party?

Comment: I think it must be:
salesDoc.SetValue("sold_to_party", <MY_VALUE>); salesDoc.SetValue("ship_to_party", <MY_VALUE>);
But it ist long time ago I used the NCO3

Comment: Thans for the suggestion Chris but when I used this code I got the error "Element sold_to_party of container metadata BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2 unknown". I am unable to pass this parameter Sold to party to the BAPI, can you please share any code example how to pass this parameter. Thanks..

Comment: What bapi are you calling "BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1" or "BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2". In your question you wrote, that you use "BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1", but now it seems that you use "BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2". "BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2" has complete different calling structure. See: http://www.se80.co.uk/sapfms/b/bapi/bapi_salesorder_createfromdat2.htm

Comment: I am using BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work with you. All you need is to append the lines to the structure.

Further, I do recommend that you use BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT2 since this is the latest and you don't need to multiply the Order Qty * 1000.

I was lost in the object structure of the salesDoc but thanks to VS you can add a watch on the salesDoc and you will be able to figure out the whole structure.

```
        RfcRepository repo = destination.Repository;
        IRfcFunction salesDoc = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_SALESORDER_CREATEFROMDAT1");
        IRfcFunction salesDocCommit = repo.CreateFunction("BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT");

        IRfcStructure salesHeader = salesDoc.GetStructure("ORDER_HEADER_IN");

        IRfcTable salesItems = salesDoc.GetTable("ORDER_ITEMS_IN");
        IRfcTable salesPartners = salesDoc.GetTable("ORDER_PARTNERS");

        IRfcStructure salesItemsStruct = salesItems.Metadata.LineType.CreateStructure();
        IRfcStructure salesPartnersStruct = salesPartners.Metadata.LineType.CreateStructure();


        //Sales Header
        salesHeader.SetValue("DOC_TYPE", "ZDLR");
        salesHeader.SetValue("SALES_ORG", "1000");
        salesHeader.SetValue("DISTR_CHAN", "00");
        salesHeader.SetValue("DIVISION", "00");
        salesHeader.SetValue("SALES_OFF", "1001");

        //Sales Items
        salesItemsStruct.SetValue("ITM_NUMBER", "323");
        salesItemsStruct.SetValue("PLANT", "1001");
        salesItemsStruct.SetValue("MATERIAL", "20000206");
        salesItemsStruct.SetValue("TARGET_QTY", "200");
        salesItemsStruct.SetValue("REQ_QTY", "200");
        salesItems.Append(salesItemsStruct); // Append to Structure

        // Partner
        salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_ROLE", "AG"); //Sold to Party 
        salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_NUMB", "102003");
        salesPartners.Append(salesPartnersStruct); // Append to Structure

        salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_ROLE", "WE"); //Ship to Party
        salesPartnersStruct.SetValue("PARTN_NUMB", "102003"); 
        salesPartners.Append(salesPartnersStruct); // Append to Structure


        RfcSessionManager.BeginContext(destination);
        salesDoc.Invoke(destination);
        salesDocCommit.Invoke(destination);
        RfcSessionManager.EndContext(destination);
        return "";
```